# Are there any tutorials for OMPL in Python?

Tags: motion-planning, python

I want to learn and understand the Open Motion Planning Library (OMPL) through Python as I don't have much experience with C++. Almost all tutorials are written in C++ and there are some demos in Python. I installed and checked OMPL version 1.5. It worked well, and I want to know more about other applications. Are there any resources or suggestions on how I can learn OMPL through Python?

I use Ubuntu 18.04
Python 3.6
OMPL 1.5

Comment: ask at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

OMPL does have Python bindings.  There is a section on the site documentation explaining the [differences between the Python and C++ APIs and some samples](https://ompl.kavrakilab.org/python.html).  That may provide you with a starting points, though I don't see any full tutorials using Python as of this writing ([alternate long-lived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200426172449/https://ompl.kavrakilab.org/python.html)).

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of the link I just wanted to learn OMPL using Python, but I think it's too difficult with this limited resources